# Using super() with multiple inheritance

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, super

The code is quite self-explanatory. I want to call both class `A` and class `B` `__init__` methods.

Code:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, age):
        self.age = age

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        A.__init__(self, name)
        B.__init__(self, age)


    def display(self):
        print(self.name, self.age)

c = C("xyz", 12)
c.display()
```

Output:

```
xyz 12
```

I want to use `super()` instead of explicitly stating

```
A.__init__(self, name)
B.__init__(self, age)
```

I am unable to find any resource for the same, need help.

The following does not work:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(A, self).__init__()
        self.name = name

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, age):
        super(B, self).__init__()
        self.age = age

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        # A.__init__(self, name)
        # B.__init__(self, age)
        super(C, self).__init__(name, age)

    def display(self):
        print(self.name, self.age)

c = C("xyz", 12)
c.display()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Python's super() work with multiple inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance)

Comment: Nope I tried using a few solutions, it didn't work

Comment: Are you sure? Does `super(A, self).__init__(name)` work?

Comment: If the two super classes don't have compatible `__init__` signatures, you can't do it with just one `super` call. What you're doing is as good as it gets.

Comment: @NguyenThaiBinh nope it didn't, you can see the question again, I have edited my question

Comment: You can only pass in parent classes, `A` and `B`,  as `super()`'s first parameter. If your intention is to use one super to initialise both classes, then as @deceze commented, you can't.

Comment: are you using python 2 or 3?

Comment: I am using python 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an instance of `C`, it's better if you pass keyword arguments so that you know which is which. Positional arguments work too but with keyword arguments, you don't have to worry about messing up the order of arguments.

Then since `C` defers the definition of `self.name` and `self.age` to parent classes, you immediately pass all arguments up the heirarchy using `super().__init__(**kwargs)`. The best thing about inheritance is that child classes don't even need to know about the parameters it doesn't handle. The first parent class is `A`, so `self.name` is defined there. The next parent class in the method resolution order is `B`, so from `A`, you pass the remaining keyword arguments to `B`, using `super().__init__(**kwargs)` yet again.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, name, **kwargs):
        self.name = name
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, age, **kwargs):
        self.age = age
        super().__init__(**kwargs)    # this is actually not needed but in case you have other base classes after B, might come in handy

class C(A,B):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def display(self):
        print(self.name, self.age)

c = C(name="xyz",age=12)
c.display()
```

Output:

```
xyz 12
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a metaclass in my public library just for this purpose. Set the metaclass of the first base class.

It makes any inheriters automatically call its' bases `__init__`s without having to worry about `super()` calls allowing you to write cleaner code. It's also forgiving as it sets missing args to `None`.

```py
from generallibrary import AutoInitBases

class A(metaclass=AutoInitBases):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name

class B:
    def __init__(self,age):
        self.age=age

class C(A,B):
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        pass

    def display(self):
        print(self.name,self.age)

c=C("xyz",12)
c.display()
```

```
xyz 12
```

I don't care much about backward compatibility so make sure to lock the version if you install it. It supports python 3.8 and 3.9

`pip install generallibrary==2.9.1`

Comment: What does the metaclass actually do, and why do you think it's a good tool here?

Comment: Updated the explanation, I know it's a bit out there but it really makes multiple inheritances much easier to work with

Comment: The python system is pretty well designed. I'm pretty sure introducing a bunch of unexpected behavior is not going to make it easier. That being said, downvote removed.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to use `kwargs` in all your initializers, and pass through the ones you don't care about.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, name, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.name = name

class B:
    def __init__(self, age, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.age = age

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self, name, age, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(name=name, age=age, **kwargs)

    def display(self):
        print(self.name, self.age)
```

By isolating the arguments you care about from `kwargs`, you ensure that all `kwargs` get consumed before you hit `object`.